# AngularJS Keypress Keycode Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keypress, keycode

I'm trying to write an AngularJS directive to run a function when the Escape key is pressed:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" custom-keypress="consoleLog()">
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.consoleLog = function () {
    console.log('works')
  }
});

app.directive('customKeypress', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 27) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Unfortunately when I press the Escape key nothing happens.

[Here's my Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XZrmKPuIJPcvoyxcexlh?p=preview).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You got a typo there... `ngEnter` v/s `customKeypress` ?

Comment: Try refreshing the plunk - should be `custom-keypress` and `customKeypress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are targeting the wrong attribute value on your `$eval` call.  Forked and fixed - http://plnkr.co/edit/0fsKoHAAgTvl4l2z8SfJ?p=preview

should be: `scope.$eval(attrs.customKeypress);`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you don't have `ng-enter` attribute. It should be:

```
scope.$eval(attrs.customKeypress);
```

Comment: Try refreshing the plunk - should be `custom-keypress` and `customKeypress`